# how to get max(column) in a table using spring-data-jpa derived query method, where column is a number type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get max(uid) from users table

```
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    private Long uid;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    Long findMaxUid();
}
```

I am trying to call the findMaxUid() function in the userRepository in applicationRunner method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
            userRepository.save(UserEntity.builder().uid(101L).build());
            System.out.println(userRepository.findMaxUid());
        };
    }

}
```

I am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Long com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UserRepository.findMaxUid(); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Long com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UserRepository.findMaxUid(); No property 'findMaxUid' found for type 'UserEntity'
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Long com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UserRepository.findMaxUid(); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Long com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UserRepository.findMaxUid(); No property 'findMaxUid' found for type 'UserEntity'
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'findMaxUid' found for type 'UserEntity'
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject) `Max` is not a supported query keyword so you might have to supply your own custom query instead. But you could try to use something like `findTopByOrderByUidDesc()` and read the uid only.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT MAX(u.uid) FROM UserEntity u")
Long findMaxUid();
```

Comment: or you could order and get first entity Entitiy
`UserEntity findFirstOrderByUidDesc()`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, you could try the following (disclaimer: I can't test it right now so I'm not sure this will work):

```
interface UidView {
  Long getUid();
} 

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
  //order by uid, get the top entry having the largest uid, use a projection to only read the uid
  UidView findTopByOrderByUidDesc();

  //default method that translates the call and return type
  default Long findMaxUid() {
    UidView top = findTopByOrderByUidDesc();
    return top != null ? top.getUid() : null; 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Thomas. unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: @JanapureddyRamakrishna can you elaborate on "it did not help"? Any exception? And did you try without the default method just to be sure?

Comment: If I try with default method
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UidView from class jdk.proxy2.$Proxy91 (com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UidView is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; jdk.proxy2.$Proxy91 is in module jdk.proxy2 of loader 'app')

Comment: If I remove the default method then also same error

Comment: Read those error messages carefully: "failed to access class" and "com.orgofarmsgroup.repository.UidView is in unnamed module of loader 'app'" do _not_ indicate an error with the repository but with your build in general, e.g. you might need to edit your module-info.java